# Como permitir que os usuários usem domínios próprios como URL de seus perfis?

Tags: apache, servidor, dns

Eu tenho um site onde cada usuário tem um perfil com uma URL do tipo `www.site.com/username123`. Agora, eu quero permitir que cada usuário possa utilizar um domínio próprio como `www.username123.com` que aponte para o seu perfil.

O Tumblr faz exatamente o que eu quero (screenshot abaixo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assumindo que eu esteja utilizando PHP e Apache:

1. Que tipo de servidor eu preciso? Posso utilizar hospedagem compartilhada?
2. Que configurações preciso fazer no servidor?
3. Que tipo de registro DNS o usuário precisa criar pra funcionar?